# LWUIT: Which subset of html and css can the htmlcomponent read?

Tags: java, java-me, lwuit

I noticed it can't read/parse everything you throw at it. It reads normal html, because i can see that, but i can't see the css that i use to make it look nice. although in the docs they say that css is possible. So i wonder, which part of css can it show?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, it supports most of the basic elements(Images, Fonts, Lists, Tables, Forms and even CSS except js,frames etc) of `XHTML Mobile Profile 1.0`. You can say almost 90% is supported.

A full list of `XHTML-MP 1.0` elements can be found [here](http://htmllint.itc.keio.ac.jp/htmllint/tagslist.cgi?HTMLVersion=XHTML-MP).

A general list of what is supported and whats not is is described in [this blog](http://www.nextgenmoco.com/2010/02/mobile-web-and-html-inside-javame-with.html).